# DIV on middle with vertical layout, div on left with horizontal layout

Tags: jquery, css, html, css-float

I can't get things working with floated elements...
Here is what I'm trying to do :

I have 3 divs with this layout when screen is "narrow" (like an mobile in portrait)

```
BB
AA
AA
CC
```

BUT, and here is the impossible thing, I want them to layout like this when window is wider (like a desktop browser or a landscape mobile) :

```
AABB
AACC
```

Is this possible just with CSS or must I need to go with something like jquery and stuff ?

This is driving me crazy. :p

Thanks !

Comment: BTW, I said hello, StackOverflow remove it from my post ! (not sure why)

Comment: No solutions was good, seems impossible just with CSS for only 3 divs, I used js to show/hide a div depending on windows size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what look like:

**html:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">AA</div>
    <div class="box">BB</div>
    <div class="box">CC</div>
    <div class="box">DD</div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.wrapper {
    float:left;
    width:100%;

}
.wrapper .box {
    float:left;
    width:50%;

}
@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 320px){
    .wrapper .box {
        width:100%;  
    }
}
```

if you target to work on mobile put this before the end tag of `</head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AG66a/5/)

hope this help you.....

Answer (score 2):

If you just float the elements it should work more or less automatically, and `@media` queries are at your side.  However if you want a break on the odd elements (counting from zero) at any width, that's not a problem either:

```
div:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: both;
}
```

Note that this has no effect if the screen is small enough to make all the elements stack vertically.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/bBEE5/

Comment: this is not an general idea.you cant do it three column for example.

Comment: @imsiso he didn't ask to do 3 columns though .. you can just update the rule to use `:nth-child(3n)` if you wanted it to be 3 columns